# How to get content page facebook with post-id?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I'm trying with this code but it doesn't work .

```
$page_posts = file_get_contents('https://graph.facebook.com/'.$post_id.'?fields=message&access_token='.$token); 
$pageposts = json_decode($page_posts); 
foreach ($pageposts->data as $fppost) 
{
    if (property_exists($fppost,'message')) 
    {                
         print $fppost->message.'</br>';                
    }
}
```

With [Graph API Explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/145634995501895/?method=GET&path=20531316728_10152364602581729%3Ffields%3Dmessage&version=) it works!

Can you show me the best way to get message with post-id in php?

Answer (score 0):

The output of the API call will be of format:

> {
>    
>       "message": ".........", 
>   
>        "id": "..........", 
>   
>        "created_time": "..........."
>   
> }

The result isn't an array. Also there's no key `data` in the result.

Simply get the message with-

```
print $pageposts->message.'</br>';
```